# Merge on specific columns with null values in key columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two data frames that has null values in the key columns , I have already found a way to merge the two data frames but the issue is I don't want all the columns from df2 and just specific columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Email': ['example@gmail.com', 'example@gmail.com', np.nan, np.nan],
    'How long has your business been operating?': ['2 year', np.nan, '2 year', np.nan],
    'How many employees do you have currently?': [np.nan, '2 employees', np.nan, '1 employee'],

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a separate DataFrame with non-null email addresses
df_non_null_email = df.dropna(subset=['Email'])

df = df[df['Email'].isnull()]

# Perform the group by operation on the separate DataFrame
result_df = df_non_null_email.groupby('Email', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
# Replace empty strings with np.nan in all columns
result_df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Concatenate the grouped DataFrame back to the original DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, result_df], ignore_index=True)
```

and this is the second dataframe

```
data2 = {  'Email address': ['example@gmail.com', np.nan,np.nan],
    'Any disability?': ['yes',np.nan,np.nan],
'Sexuality': [np.nan,'yes',np.nan]
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
select_column = ['Any disability?']
```

This is the how I am merging the two data frames

```
# Merge the two DataFrames on the 'Email' column
merged_df = df.merge(df2[pd.notnull(df2['Email address'])], how='left', right_on='Email address',left_on='Email')
```

This is the output I am getting

[image]

I only want the second last column disability from the other dataframe like this

[image]

I have to do this step for multiple data frames so looking for a clean solution

Comment: Please add data sample and expected output

Comment: I have added the output I am getting and what I am expecting

Comment: You would like to leave in the merged dataframe only rows where there is an email address?

Answer (score 0):

since there is no expected output it is unclear, but do you want only the `Any disability?` column from your df2 ? why not filter the df2 and merge ?

```
df2 = df2[['Any disability?', 'Email address']]
merged_df = df.merge(df2[pd.notnull(df2['Email address'])], how='left', right_on='Email address',left_on='Email').drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: I have added the expected outcome as well. while this may work , I am trying to find a neat solution for this as I have to perform this for multiple other data frames as well

Comment: in that case, first you have to standardize your columns, and make list of selected columns and merge them
'